# Controllers not found when simulating ur5 arm attached to husky in gazebo

Tags: gazebo, rviz, moveit, husky, ur5

I am trying to simulate a Husky robot with a UR5 Arm attached using [this](https://github.com/husky/husky_manipulation) tutorial. I've managed to get the Husky with the UR5 attached in gazebo, but when I plan and execute an instruction to move the arm, it fails. I'm getting this error message:

```
Unable to identify any set of controllers that can actuate the specified joints: [ ur_arm_elbow_joint ur_arm_shoulder_lift_joint ur_arm_shoulder_pan_joint ur_arm_wrist_1_joint ur_arm_wrist_2_joint ur_arm_wrist_3_joint ]
[ERROR] [1692315113.447379041, 1346.540000000]: Known controllers and their joints:
[ERROR] [1692315113.447400973, 1346.540000000]: Apparently trajectory initialization failed
```

I pushed my code to [this](https://github.com/vivekalumootil/husky-ur5-moveit) github repo. Please check it out. I've been stuck on this for a few days and would greatly appreciate some help.

I did notice that running `roslaunch abc_husky_moveit_config husky_ur_moveit_planning_execution.launch` gave me the following error messages:

`Action client not connected: controller_1/follow_joint_trajectory`
and
`Action client not connected: controller_2/follow_joint_trajectory`.

I noticed using `rostopic list | grep controller` that the ros topics for each controller appear while it outputs "waiting for controller_1/follow_joint_trajectory to come up" and then disappears after when it prints action client not found.

Answer (score 0):

The repository you've linked seems to assume that you have the appropriate controllers installed for `ros_control` to interface with. If you don't have them installed, this error can come up. You can install the basic `ros_control` controllers using

```
sudo apt install ros-<ros version>-ros-controllers
```

where '<ros version>' is your ros version (noetic, galactic, etc).

Comment: I've already done this. I did notice that running `roslaunch abc_husky_moveit_config husky_ur_moveit_planning_execution.launch` gave me the following error messages: `Action client not connected: controller_1/follow_joint_trajectory, Action client not connected: controller_2/follow_joint_trajectory`. I noticed using `rostopic list | grep 'controller` that the ros topics for each controller appear while it outputs `waiting for controller_1/follow_joint_trajectory to come up` and then disappears after when it prints action client not connected.

Comment: @VivekA Then this is a very different error with information that would have been relevant to your question. The error "waiting for ___" comes up when an action is not available, which is often because of a namespacing issue: look for the action in a different namespace, and if it is there, move it (this could be caused by something as simple as a typo). If it isn't, find what should be providing that action and ensure it's being launched.